# Can't upload 5mb file using AJAX file uploader

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am using the file uploader plugin (from: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) to upload files to my website.

If you are using a moden web browser (like Firefox 6 or Chrome 13), then it uploads by streaming the file in the POST body, and can give you a progress bar.  If you're using IE (or an old browser), it falls back on the standard $_FILES (using a hidden iFrame).

Everything was working fine, but suddenly I can't upload 5MB files in Chrome or Firefox.  When I upload a 5MB file in Chome or Firefox I get a 500 error and my PHP code is never even ran.  If I use Internet Explorer (which uses $_FILES), it works fine.

This has to be a configuration problem, as my PHP code never even runs.  So, I checked my settings.

*/etc/php.ini*

```
upload_max_filesize = 15M
post_max_size = 16M
```

I looked for `LimitRequestBody`, but that's nowhere to be found (and the default is unlimited).

Settings look right.  I debugged this for a while, and I can not figure out what is wrong.

Is there a setting I'm missing?  The server has suhosin installed, if that matters.

I know my PHP code works, as files less than 4MB upload fine (on all browsers).  I only have a problem with files bigger than 5MB (using Chrome/Firefox).  The weird thing is, this works fine on my test server, but not my production server.  They probably have different settings (suhosin is on production, but not on test).

Comment: Are there any messages in your web server logs?

Comment: @voretaq7: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5242881 bytes).  Let's change `memory_limit` to 64M, see if that works.

Comment: @voretaq7: Changing `memory_limit` to 64M worked!  But will that be a problem if multiple people are uploading at the same time?

Comment: It shouldn't be -- how much RAM does your server have and how many concurrent connections are you expecting? (64M or 128M is what I usually set PHP to on machines with 4-8GB of RAM - the chance of every apache process sucking up that much RAM is infinitesimal unless you have an extreme use case...)

Comment: @voretaq7: 2GB, I think.  But if I have 100 people all uploading 10MB files at the same time, that'd be 1GB.

Comment: But think about how often that exact pathological scenario will happen outside of a contrived test (hint: it's not likely at any reasonable number of requests/second...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is [here](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/server/php.php) and specifically in the [stream_copy_to_stream ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php)
which seems to be a memory hog because (and I only assume) it copies the whole(?) file
to be uploaded to memory.
So check [suhosin.memory_limit](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.memory_limit) and memory_limit in php.ini

PS I don't know the etiquette here if I should submit it as an answer or a comment, but I'll
leave it as an answer for the time.

Comment: `memory_limit` was the culprit.  I changed it to 64M and, it's working.  I wonder if an alternative to `stream_copy_to_stream` will help.